# awk + count strings in file

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

we have huge file like this

this is partial list in the file

```
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 31   Leader: 1007    Replicas: 1007,1008,1009        Isr: 1009,1007,1008
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 32   Leader: 1008    Replicas: 1008,1009,1010        Isr: 1010,1009,1008
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 33   Leader: 1009    Replicas: 1009,1010,1006        Isr: 1009,1010,1006
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 34   Leader: 1010    Replicas: 1010,1006,1007        Isr: 1006,1007,1010
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 35   Leader: 1006    Replicas: 1006,1008,1009        Isr: 1006,1009,1008
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 36   Leader: 1007    Replicas: 1007,1009,1010        Isr: 1010,1007,1009
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 37   Leader: 1008    Replicas: 1008,1010,1006        Isr: 1006,1010,1008
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 38   Leader: 1009    Replicas: 1009,1006,1007        Isr: 1007,1009,1006
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 39   Leader: 1010    Replicas: 1010,1007,1008        Isr: 1010,1007,1008
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 40   Leader: 1006    Replicas: 1006,1009,1010        Isr: 1006,1010,1009
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 41   Leader: 1007    Replicas: 1007,1010,1006        Isr: 1006,1007,1010
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 42   Leader: 1008    Replicas: 1008,1006,1007        Isr: 1006,1007,1008
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 43   Leader: 1009    Replicas: 1009,1007,1008        Isr: 1009,1007,1008
Topic: Ho_HTR_bvt     Partition: 44   Leader: 1010    Replicas: 1010,1008,1009        Isr: 1010,1009,1008
```

how to count the number - **1007** string ?

or any other word in file

Comment: The objective to count the string `1007` is unclear.  Should the string be counted when it's part of another word, as in `10071`? Should each instance of `1007` on a line be counted?

Comment: Should the string be counted when it's part of another word, as in 10071 - YES

Comment: we want to count the string in file no matter if string is part of other string and separated by separator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your example data:

```
$ grep -Fo 1007 file | wc -l
      19
```

The `grep` part of this pipeline will search for the string `1007` (the `-F` flag is used because we are doing string comparisons, not regular expression matching).  It will return each individual instance of the string on a new line due to the `-o` flag.  The number of lines returned is counted by `wc -l`.

If the string occurs twice on a line in the input data, this will count it twice.  If the string occurs as a substring of another word, it will be counted too.

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -v str="1007" '{ c += gsub(str, str) } END { print c }' file
19
```

This counts the number of times the string occurs using `gsub()` (this function returns the number of times a substitution is performed, and we apply it to each input line individually) and prints the total count at the end.  The string we're interested in is passed on the command line with `-v str="1007"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use awk, you can use this command:

`awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i == "word/number that you want to search") c++ }'END'{print c}' filename`

Comment: Note that this will not count substrings though.

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
awk '{print gsub("1007",$0)}' filename | awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$1}END{print sum}'

-0-praveenk_22@:~ $
```

output

```
awk '{print gsub("1007",$0)}' u.txt | awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$1}END{print sum}'
19
-0-praveenk_22@:~ $
```